# Angular2: call child component method

Tags: angular

I have a component called `CardComponent` with following markup

```
<div class="header">
    <!-- My card style header -->
</div>

<div class="content">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
<div>

<div class="footer">
    <!-- My card style footer -->
    <!-- Need a button here (explained below) -->
</div>
```

I'm using this as following

```
<card>
    <component-a></component-a>
</card>

<card>
    <component-b></component-b>
</card>
```

It works fine. However, I need to add a button in the card footer which will call a method of the respective child component.

For example, the button on the first card will call a function in `component-a` and the second in `component-b`.

can I do this without a pipeline in my main/container component? and also without the need to do a `<component-a #var>`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using `@ViewChild` in your parent component:

```
@ViewChild(ComponentA) theComponent: ComponentA;
```

where ComponentA is the reference of your component name.

Then you can use child components methods with this field,

```
theComponent.method()
```

As suggested by @Günter:

"If it's passed to `<ng-content>` you need to use `@ContentChild()` instead of `@ViewChild()`. `@ViewChild()` only looks up elements in the template. You also should mention that theComponent won't be set before `ngAfterContentInit()` is called."

Comment: But then `CardComponent` needs to be aware of `ComponentA` right?

Comment: @Салман Assuming `CardComponent` is `ComponentA`'s parent: yes.

Comment: Hmm... As I shown in the question, `CardComponent` can be used to wrap any component, in which case it is not possible for `CardComponent` to know all the possible children

Comment: If it's passed to `<ng-content>` you need to use `@ContentChild()` instead of `@ViewChild()`. `@ViewChild()` only looks up elements in the `template`. You also should mention that `theComponent` won't be set before `ngAfterContentInit()` is called.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `@ContentChild` also need the `ComponentA` reference as its param right?

Comment: @Салман how are the `<card>` elements appended? can add a little more detail to your question.

Comment: Manually, we may add any number of cards when needed. I can just make sure that the first and the only content child will be the one I'm interested in. Does that make it any easier?

Comment: @Салман `@Content()` child takes the component or directives type as argument exactly as `@ViewChild()`. Alternatively (for both) a string can be passed that needs to match a template variables name.

Comment: Can't I just query all content children and pick first!

Comment: You can't query all independent of their type. You can only query by type or by template variable name. You can use `@ContentChildren(ComponentA)` instead of `@ContentChild(ComponentA)` to get all `ComponentA` instances though.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `EventEmitter` (`doSomething`) to your `CardComponent` that emits an event when the button is clicked and then

```
<card (doSomething)="componenta.aFunction()">
    <component-a #componenta></component-a>
</card>

<card (doSomething)="componentb.aFunction()">
    <component-b #componentb></component-b>
</card>
```